# After forcefully shut down ,it was unable to start

Tags: boot

I had to forcefully shutdown my workstation due to a system hang. After sometime, I tried rebooting it & but is not booting. It says; `HDD is not detected`. What can I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking inside `BIOS` whether the hard disk is listed there?? If not, please check and let us know first. Usually it should be <kbd>F12</kbd> or a specified key will be shown at the `POST` screen while booting.